# Laravel 5.2: How to read and show the checked item(s) of a group of checkbox in edit page?

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.2: How to read and show the checked item(s) of a group of checkbox in edit page?

For example:
**view:**

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) !!}
  <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox[]" value="1">apple
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox[]" value="2">pear
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="checkbox[]" value="3">grape
    </label>
  </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**controller:**

```
$checkboxes = $request->input('checkbox');
```

I turn it into JSON with json_encode() and save them all in one column.After this, when I access the edit page,how to read and show them? That being said, the checked items will be checked,and the not checked items will not be checked in edit page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox[]" value="1" {{in_array($checkboxes, 1) ? 'checked' : ''}}>
```

Comment: thanks very much! and one more thing,I want the checked item(s) to be shown in "show" page,the content of the checkboxes are apple,pear,grape,not 1,2,3.How to do it?